# Node.js stops working when I log out

Tags: node.js, centos, cpanel, whm

I logged in as root to my CentOS 5/cPanel server and I typed the following:

```
cd /usr/local/bin/
git clone --depth 1 http://github.com/joyent/node.git
cd node
git checkout origin/v0.4 # optional.  Note that master is unstable.
export JOBS=2 # optional, sets number of parallel commands.
mkdir ~/local
./configure --prefix=$HOME/local/node
make
make install
echo 'export PATH=$HOME/local/node/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.profile
source ~/.profile
```

It seems to be working fine until I log out from the server and log back in it's as it wasn't installed:

```
[~]# node test.js
-bash: node: command not found
```

If I type: `source ~/.profile` it starts working again until I log out.

Please help. Thanks.

EDIT:

This is the content of my .bash_profile, how should I change it?

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
unset USERNAME
```

Comment: Because the `PATH` is only set up properly in your profile. add `node` to your PATH properly.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/102932/adding-a-directory-to-path-in-centos

Comment: Thanks it worked but this seems messing with the server's core files. I think .bash_profile or something is more suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading that file, **it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the *first one* that exists and is readable.** The --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.

Maybe you have a `.bash_profile` and it's being used instead?

Comment: `echo 'export PATH=$HOME/local/node/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile`